# Android Studio 2.1 NavigationDrawer (Framents)

Tags: android, fragment, navigation-drawer

I'm using Android Stduio 2.1. I generated a Navigation Drawer Activity.

How can I call other Activitys or Fragments with the Same Navigation Drawer.
But the Navigation Menu must be still there in every Fragment or Activity I call. How can I manage this?

This is the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, GPS_Overview2.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    //GPS AN/AUS Überprüfung
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        Toast.makeText(this, this.getText(R.string.GPS_AN) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

//GPS An Message
private void showGPSDisabledAlertToUser(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.GPS_ERROR))
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.GPS_SETTINGS),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                            Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(
                                    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
                        }
                    });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.cancel),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.gps_overview) {


    } else if (id == R.id.tachoscheibe) {

    } else if (id == R.id.gps_overview) {

    } else if (id == R.id.settings) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.settings) {

    } else if (id == R.id.exit) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

}
```

This is the activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

When you need more information only write a comment.

Greetings form Germany

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Intent` when to want to go go to another activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,newActivity.class);
```

And

```
 @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.gps_overview) {
       startActivity(intent);
} else if (id == R.id.tachoscheibe) {

} else if (id == R.id.gps_overview) {

} else if (id == R.id.settings) {

} else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

} else if (id == R.id.settings) {

} else if (id == R.id.exit) {
    System.exit(0);
}

DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
return true;
}
```

For changing fragment you can you

```
 Fragment fragment = null;
 fragmentClass = Fragment.class;
    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_fragment, fragment).commit();
```